# Using Javascript, How do I check which css left value is greatest in a group of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know which of these three elements has the greatest left value. 
This is what I have, is it correct?

```
    var leftOne = document.getElementById('one').css.left;
    var leftTwo = document.getElementById('two').css.left;
    var leftThree = document.getElementById('three').css.left;
    var max123 = Math.max(leftThree, leftTwo, leftOne);
```

Comment: Will all of the divs have the same class/be a decendent of some element that can be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joseph the Dreamer is right, it's `style.left`. But you also need to convert these figures into integers for the `Max` function. This is my code, which worked fine:

Javascript:

```
function test() {
    var leftOne = document.getElementById('one').style.left;
    var leftTwo = document.getElementById('two').style.left;
    var leftThree = document.getElementById('three').style.left;
    var max123 = Math.max(parseInt(leftThree), parseInt(leftTwo), parseInt(leftOne));
    alert(max123);
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="one" style="left:30px">aaaaa</div>
<div id="two" style="left:22px">bbbbb</div>
<div id="three" style="left:34px">ccccc</div>
<a href="#" onclick="test()">test</a>
```

Result: 34

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that supposed to be `style` instead of `css`?

```
document.getElementById('ID_HERE').style.left
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery if all of the divs can be selected using some selector (for this its using class `maxleft`)

```
var maxleft = 0;
$('.maxleft').css("left", function(idx, left) {
    maxleft = Math.max(maxleft, left); 
});
```